# iOS button vector image problems

Tags: swift3, uibutton, xcode8, ios10, vector-graphics

I am using a vector image (PDF) as button image, and I the button suppose to change the image in the button when button changes state. States like disabled, highlighted etc. But the image does not change as the button state changes.

What I did:

1. I added the vector files to assets library.
2. I am choosing "single vector" as the scale factor.
3. I am selecting the image in the attribute inspector for the button and setting the images for all states.
4. I run the app on simulator.
5. I am tapping on the button on simulator but the image does not change even if the state changes.

Why?

Update: I think that the state changes too quickly and I can't observe the change. What can be done for that?

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: There is no code. Just vector images and configuration in attribute inspector.